# I cannot see correlation in the ACF/PACF and author can

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, correlation, time-series

I am following a tutorial on time series analysis. The plots below are of percent changes of prices for S&P500 index. The tutorial says the following, which I disagree with or don't understand.

> It's quite similar to white noise, isn't it? However, there appears to
> be some significant serial correlation in the ACF, and PACF plots
> around lags 1, 10, 15, 18 and 21.

**I don't see significant serial correlation in the ACF and PACF at lags 1,10,15,18 and 21. Do you?**

[image]

Comment: You don't specify the data in your dataset (data ranges, frequency of sampling, timing of sampling, et c.).  When I perform this analysis on the past two years of daily closing data, there is a huge spike at lag 0 days and decreasing magnitude (so sign indifferent) spikes at lags 7, 6, 2, 1, 5, ... days.  Since you don't specify your dataset, I see no way anyone could verify your computation.

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry, it is for daily adjClose from yahoo data for ticker ^GSPC between '2014/12/31' and '2017/12/31'. You shouldn't need the data - I've provided a ACF and PACF above.